# Using 'a' + 'kind of' + noun

Tags: articles, usage

Is there any difference in using `kind of` + `noun` with or without `a` at the beginning?

For example,

> It is kind of animal.

vs

> It is a kind of animal.

Comment: You should find and add some examples with context. It is kind of important. Meaning *kind of* exists but the meaning is different.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The first example is 'wrong' in standard English.

Just as you would say:

> It is **an** animal

you need the indefinite article before 'kind of animal'.

> It is **a** kind of animal.